# Как при добавлении произвольного поля к посту, проверять какой у него шаблон

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

Поле добавляется через functions.php add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_fields', 1). Название файла шаблона хранится в метаполе _wp_page_template. Прочитал в гайдах, что можно вывести посты с определенным шаблоном в цикле через WP_Query, а можно ли использовать в данном случае WP_Query для проверки при добавлении метаполя к посту, не могу сообразить как правильно создать условие.
В meta_key лежит _wp_page_template, в meta_value имя шаблона, а в post_id соответственно id поста.

Comment: Покажите ваш код WP_Query

Comment: Да нет кода. WP_Query он же для цикла, а там вовсе не цикл, а условие нужно.